# How to newline in namesection of deedy-resume?

Tags: deedy-resume

I'm using overleaf plushCV deedy-resume to build resume.
https://github.com/sansquoi/PlushCV

In namesection as follow

```
\documentclass[]{plushcv}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\begin{document}

 \namesection{Firstname}{Lastname}{Full Stack Software Engineer}{\contactline{\href{https://www.something.github.io}{something.github.io}}{\href{https://www.github.com/sansquoi}{something-something}}{\href{https://www.linkedin.com/mazumders}{somethingverlong}}{\href{mailto:shubham.mazumder@gmail.com}{first.last@email.com}}{\href{tel:+1999999999}{9999999999}}}

\end{document}  \documentclass[]{article}
```

For long names , it overflow and throws a warning
`Overfull \hbox (28.41821pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 50--50`

I was unable to remove some section such as linkedin because i think it is required to put . I tried to use
`{\\}` or `{\newline}` into namesection , but it didnt worked.

Is there any way ?
Thank you

Comment: Can you please provide complete minimal code, showing your problem? Thanks

Comment: Hello @MS-SPO here is my example https://www.overleaf.com/read/gbnbcfmbddtj

Comment: Thanks. Please be so kind to copy those about 9 lines of code here. Will make replies easier and more frequent ;-)

Comment: Sorry, i updated my question

Comment: Hello i solved it in another form, by looking into source code. I made new command \contactline without linkedin and now it doesnt overflow.

Comment: Fine :) Would be interesting if you'd share your new code as an answer (see below), so other people can reuse it later. Thanks.